# cordova-plugin-insomnia not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I follow the instructions written there: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-insomnia

1. cordova plugin add
   https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
2. cordova prepare

Then in index.js  i wrote :

```html
if (window.plugins.insomnia && window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake) {
  window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake(onSuccess,onError);
} else {
    alert("insomnia plugin missing");
}
```

onSuccess is correctly invoked and executed. So i assumed the installation is correct.

But the screen of my SamSung Galaxy XCover 3 running on Android 5.1.1 sleeps after few seconds. Cordova 6.3.1

Do you have an idea of what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: same problem with https://github.com/zoxxx/PhoneGap-KeepScreenOn-plugin

Comment: When i call awake juste after the device ready event, insomnia work well.
But when called after the photo gallery, insomnia does not work.
The photo gallery i use is imagepicker: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

Comment: similar to the issue https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/29

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the issue github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/29 
I do not use Insomnia anymore.