# Cordova Insomnia plugin not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I'm developing an app using Cordova, and the Insomnia plugin is perfect for what I need.
But I can't make it work. To make everything as simple as possible, I created a new Cordova project, installed the plugin automatically (using the CLI) and add the following lines in the original Cordova index.html file to call the `KeepAwake` command:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Insomnia.js"></script>

<script>
window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
  </script>
```

But it's not working. The phone still auto-lock after 30s. I'm using an iPhone 5s running iOS 10.3.3 and Cordova iOS version 4.4.0.

What's wrong???

Thank you very much!

---

Code from comment below:

```
<script> 

function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); } 

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods // 
function onDeviceReady() { window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake() }

</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors? cause this plugin might not be ready yet. Have you already tried to put window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake into the deviceready-callback function and call it there?

Comment: There is no error message. But I have not tried to put window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake into the deviceready-callback function and call it from there. I just don't know how to do it... ;(

Comment: Then [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/blob/master/www/docs/en/1.6.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.md#full-example) example might help you, keep in mind that there are several approaches of how to listen for deviceready-event. that example is just one. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Blauharley, but it didn't work. That's the code I used to call:<script>
  function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
function onDeviceReady() {
 window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
</script>

Comment: Thanks, is this code really complete? There should be a } (curly-brace) at the end. So please modify the inserted code in your question.

Comment: Sorry @Blauharley, I just didn't copy all the code. Here it is complete:<script>
  function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
function onDeviceReady() {
 window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()
 }
 
</script>                                                                                                           But still not working  :(

Comment: Ok, have you already tried to run window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake() in your console? If there is no error, the plugin is installed and should work as expected. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Blauharley, but it still don't work... :(

Comment: Hi @alvaro562003, I saw this tour post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528961/cordova-plugin-insomnia-not-working - where you say you don't use the plugin Insomnia anymore. What do you use instead? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you referred the documentation? [Here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin)

You have to Copy **Insomnia.h** and **Insomnia.m** to **platforms/ios/{ProjectName}/Plugins** folder.

Comment: Yeah! It's done automatically when you install the plugin using the CLI.